# Parametric Curves to cartesian equation

Tags: homework, algebra

I have $x=t^2-3$ and $y=t+2$. I keep trying `Eliminate` and the output is always True. I just need to take these two curves and convert it to a Cartesian equation.  Every help thing I've searched for has not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you meant or not. Too small to put in comment.

```
ClearAll[x, y, t]
eq1 = x == t^2 - 3;
eq2 = y == t + 2;
Eliminate[{eq1, eq2}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]